# Can Rails be used with Jekyll and NetlifyCMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, netlify-cms

I want to switch a static Jekyll+Netlify page to a Rails project that has all the Rails features - but still have Jekyll and NetlifyCMS in the frontend(i.e. editors can upload md files on GitHub, that rebuilds all the static text).

Since Rails has it’s own view layer, I wonder if this is a feasible thing to do?

Comment: Yes. But what is is that you actually expect Rails to do in that stack? Jekyll and NetlifyCMS are both git based static page generators and Rails is a largely database driven MVC framework. You can of course have different apps mounted on different paths like people often do with a separate wordpress blog (which also serves as a honeypot).

Comment: @max Ideally, I’d want Rails to handle dynamic content like login state (render their avatar & details, if logged in). 

And Jekyll + NetlifyCMS to make static content editable without dabbling in code.

Comment: I don't think that's really going to pan out as it's completely opposed ways generating content. You might want to look for a CMS system that you can plug into rails instead.

Comment: I haven't seen any static generators like NetlifyCMS, for Rails - but I might have missed something.

One possibility is, having NetlifyCMS post to my own endpoint, rather than GitHub. But it seems non-trivial.